# Adding defines and files to multiple visual studio projects at the same time

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, project

Is there a way to add define(s) and file(s) to multiple visual studio projects at the same time ? (without doing a brutal text mode edit on the project files). I often have 40+ projects to work with (one per device model) and it's a pain to have to open each project and add the new defines and files.

If you ask what version i'm using, let's say any (EVC4, VS2005, VS2008).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Property sheets? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z7t21ew%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I usually edit the project files with `gvim`, and use `argdo` for this.  But it's particular enough that I'm not sure you could count it as an answer.  (Similarly, if I need to do this a lot, I write a Python script which will do it, and invoke that.)

Comment: @doctorelove Do you know if property sheets are compatible with Embedded visual C++ 4.0 ?